# Re-enabling stylecop

Tags: visual-studio, stylecop

I think I may have accidently disabled stylecop in my Visual Studio 2008 enviroment. If I right click a project and click "Run Stylecop", or "Stylecop Settings" nothing happens. Its the same from the Tools menu. It runs fine from Visual Studio 2005. I have Microsoft StyleCop 4.3.3.0. I was playing about with making custom rules and may have clicked Yes on a random box that popped up when there was a problem with a custom rule dll that I created, so I think this may have disabled Stylecop in my VS 2008 enviroment.

Does anyone know how to get this re-enabled? I have re-installed stylecop but to no avail.

Thanks

Neil

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved, run devenv /resetskippkgs (not from cmd though, has to be via windows interface)